# Как добавить или удалить ссылку в ilspy

Tags: c#

как добавить или удалить ссылки в ilspy если нажатием пкм этого нельзя сделать почему то. видно на фото

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, а зачем вам там добавлять или удалять что-то? ILSpy занимается декомпиляцией, чтоб вы могли только посмотреть код, и то, вы вряд-ли получите там оригинальный код проекта, он скорей всего даже не будет рабочим, из-за чего какое либо редактирование там является бесполезным.